# Running older Android apps on Android Pie

Tags: applications, 9.0-pie

I have Samsung Galaxy J9 running on Android 9 Pie. I bought [Grapher Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.grapher.pro) from the Play Store and installed it. When I tried to run it, a message was shown:

> This apk was built for an older version of Android.

Because of this, I refunded it.

Is there any way to run such apps? 
The [free version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.grapher) doesn't show the issue though.

Comment: Thanks for the error message. While I couldn't find the quoted error message, I found a similar error message on Android Pie: [This app was built for an older version of Android and may not work properly. Try checking for updates, or contact the developer](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-q-warn-apps-target-android-lollipop/), though AFAIK the app is not blocked and you're still allowed to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to change the target Android version of the app using APK Editor and change the API version. But it most likely won't work for paid apps.
 Instead, you can try to run the app in a virtual machine in which an older version of Android is installed. See [VMOS Virtual Root Android on Android-Double System](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vmos.glb).